# Package for Not Equal to sign in latex

Tags: amsmath

I am new to latex. I need to write the following equation in latex.

[image]

I have tried following packages:-

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
   L1 \cap Li \neq \Phi
```

But i constantly get error and non of the symbols gets displayed. what am i doing wrong. (i am using XeLatex as there are both English and urdu Fonts in my article)

Comment: please show a _complete_  5 or 6 line document that you tried to generate that expression. Did you put the expression in math mode `\[...\]`

Comment: It doesn't look like you are in math mode, you will need to put `$ ... $` around your equation, or `\( ... \)`. Try `$\mathbf{L}_{1} \cap \mathbf{L}_{i} \neq \mathbf{\Phi}$`

Comment: Just seen @DavidCarlisle's post. `\[ ... \]` will also work, although that will enter a displayed maths environment. Use `\[ ... \]` for displayed maths and `$ ... $` or `\( ... \)` for in-line maths

Comment: `\Phi` is probably quite wrong and the symbol means the empty set instead.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek fair point that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works for me if I complete your code to create a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\[
   L1 \cap Li \neq \Phi
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: initial result]

Admittedly, this isn't yet *quite* right because it does not look quite like the target set of symbols.

To obtain a subscript in a mathematical expression, just use `L_{<subscript>}`. To obtain the lowercase Greek letter, use `\phi` rather than `\Phi`.

```
\[
   L_1 \cap L_i \neq \phi
\]
```

[image: second pass]

## EDIT

In light of  Heiko Oberdiek's comment, for the final symbol, I'm not entirely clear which one you want but I suspect that Heiko may be right. In any case, here's a selection to choose from:

```
\[
   \phi \Phi \varphi \emptyset \varnothing
\]
```

[image: Greek letters and empty sets]

Comment: I think, it's neither `\Phi` or `\phi` but the empty set.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Thanks. I thought I'd provide a choice, just in case... ;).

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer but I have always found this to be exceedingly useful when creating complex equations or text with extraordinary symbols.

```
[http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/[1]
```